# unable to deploy microservices with different endpoint patterns using kubernetes ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to deploy a bunch of microsrvices under a single ingress contoller (in a k8s cluster).
For some of these apps the ingress requires a rewrite annotation in the ingress definition like this: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2`
and some of them do not use any rewrite annotation and are defined via a specific path.

Both apps are using the same host but different paths:

app1 uses `- path: /foo/?(.*)`

app2 uses `- path: /bar`

I can get these working seperately but not together. (with rewrite annotation the first set of apps are redirected correctly and without annotation only the 
second set of apps work)

I also tried creating different ingress definitions for different set of apps with required nginx configuration which also did not help.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: When you enable `rewrite` it will be applied for all paths, isn't possible to choose the path to apply. The best way is create another ingress without rewrite annotation. Could you please post your ingress yaml and some examples of the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get away with this by creating another ingress in a different namespace.